# OnConfiguring DbContextOptionsBuilder makes my database test fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I'm trying to test if my data is being saved in the database. When I create an ApplicationDbContext 
object with the parameter set with an in-memory database SqliteConnection connection, my test fails. I get a NullReferenceException. When I remove the override OnConfiguring method in the ApplicationDbContext object to connect with secrets that are being set with my other constructor, I don't get the exception anymore and my test passes.

What it's the simplest way to do this test while keeping my secrets setting for my connection?

These are some of my classes:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly AppSecrets _DbInfo;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IOptions<AppSecrets> 
        DbInfo) : base(options)
        {
            _DbInfo = DbInfo.Value ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(DbInfo));
        }

        // Added for unit test
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options){    }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) =>
            options.UseSqlServer($"{_DbInfo.Database};User ID={_DbInfo.User};Password= {_DbInfo.Password};{_DbInfo.Options};");

        public DbSet<UserBudget> Budgets { get; set; }
    }
```

In StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSecrets>(Configuration.GetSection("MyBudgetDB"));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

Test

```
[Fact]
        public async Task CreateBudget_CreatesCorrectly()
        {
            const string budgetName = "General budget";
            double amount = 1000.0;
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            // Run the test against one instance of the context
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                var service = new BudgetService(context);
                var cmd = new CreateBudgetCommand
                {
                    InitAmount = amount,
                };
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    Id = 123.ToString()
                };
                var recipeId = service.CreateBudget(cmd, user);
            }

            // Use a separate instance of the context to verify correct data was saved to database
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                Assert.Equal(1000.0, await context.Budgets.CountAsync());
                var budget = await context.Budgets.SingleAsync();
                Assert.Equal(amount, budget.InitAmount);
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Leidy

Comment: Set them outside of dbcontext. In `OnConfiguring` method you are registering context with SqlServer, while options registered it with Sqlite. DbContext shouldn't depend on `UseSqlServer`, do it outside of the class.

Comment: Hi Fabio. Thanks for your reply. Were do I need to move this into? Could you please give me an idea on how it should look? I attempted before to add this in the startup but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

Comment: ohh I see what you are saying.. I'm using UseSqlServer for my DbContext and then I'm using Sqlite server for my test, that conflict is firing the error. If I move the Onconfiguring method outside the class, then the DbContext won't depend on SqlServer (but wouldn't it still depend on SqlServer since I'm overriding the options with it, but I'm thinking this wouldn't affect this unit test). Wondering if my test would work if I use sqlServer in it. 
I will look first on how to set the secrets outside the DbContext. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to use a SqlConnection and manually set IOptions< AppSecrets >  in the test but this was more complex and I got the same error. I took the easiest and most appropriate rout for this(I didn't know it was this easy); by removing the OnConfiguring() method from the ApplicationDbContext and adding those settings in the StartUp:

StartUp.cs

```
 var config = new AppSecrets();
            Configuration.Bind("MyBudgetDB", config);
            services.AddSingleton(config);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    $"{config.Database};User ID={config.User};Password={config.Password};{config.Options};"));
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {   }

        public DbSet<UserBudget> Budgets { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm now able to test that my data it's being persisted using Sqlite server (preferred for me because of the Object Relational Mapping feature).

Comment: I forgot to say that I was able to add this setting in the StartUp.cs because I'm using .NET Core 2.1. I think I red somewhere you can do your secrets setting in the Startup in .NET Core 2.0 and above.